# How does strlen works with numbers?

Tags: php, strlen

I am trying to figure out how `strlen()` finds the length of a number. When I try the following:

```
echo strlen(00000000000000000000000000000000);
```

it outputs `1` but when I try

```
echo strlen(11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111);
```

it outputs `19`. Sometimes it does work properly like in this example:

```
echo strlen(19);
```

`strlen()` outputs `2`. I know I can use the following:

```
echo strlen('00000000000000000000000000000000');
```

and it will output `32` but I want to figure out how it works with numbers.

Comment: In basic maths you studied 000000 = 0 but 111111 !=1 hence so .. You can force it  `strlen((string)000000000000000000000000);`

Comment: well but `111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` is not equal to 19

Comment: the length is 61 however it outputs 19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `echo 11111111111111111111` It will echo the `1.1111111111111E+19` which is 19 characters that's why the length is 19 however if you tried `echo 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` it will ouput 1.1111111111111E+100 if you tried getting the length of it it will be 20 characters

Answer (score 3):

Because `strlen()` gives the STRING LENGTH.. 00000000000000000000000000 is not a string until it is written in quotes like "00000000000000000000000000" or '00000000000000000000000000'..

Then why `strlen(00000000000000000000000000000000)` gives output 1 and `strlen(11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111)` gives 19?

Because integer 00000000000000000000000000000000 = 0.. this means the length is 1. Whereas 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 is not equal to 1, but 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111. Hence it outputs 32.

For more you may check the documentation of [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Comment: it should be noted that the bunch of 1s has a length of 19 because it's too large to fit in an int, so it's evaluated as float and then cast to the string "1.1111111111111E+71".